# Show data in tableView from NSDictionary in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I am trying store records in UITableView each cell on reload data from a form. For this when user press add button so so multiple labels should be added to 1st indexPath then on reclicking add button again multiple cells must be added to second cell retaining first.

I am looking to store my data in

```
MyArray ({
  firstindex: 1st record
  firstindex: 2nd record
}
{
  secondindex : 1st record
  secondindex : 2nd record
})
```

Records are comming from UITextView and saving into table on each Add button click on each row with multiple entries

```
- (IBAction) Add
{
      [myDict setObject:countryTxt.text forKey:@"Country"];
        [myDict setObject:cityTxt.text forKey:@"City"];
        [myDict setObject:EscortsNumTxt1.text forKey:@"people"];
        [myDict setObject:fromDate.text forKey:@"Datetogo"];
        [myDict setObject:toDate.text forKey:@"Datetoreach"];

        [moreArr addObject:myDict];

        NSLog(@"moreDict %@",moreArr);

        numberOfrows++;

        [moreTable reloadData];
}
```

I have implemented through this way but showing repeated data on TableView Cell, I am not including frame of UILabel code, as only facing problem in fetchng

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
}

countrylbl.text = [[moreArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Country"];
        citylbl.text = [[moreArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"City"];
        people.text = [[moreArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"people"];
        toDateLbl.text = [[moreArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Datetogo"];
        fromDteLbl.text = [[moreArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Datetoreach"];
}
```

Comment: your example is totally missing the table implementation (that is the core part of your question).

Comment: I have added my UITableView code aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as NSMutableDictionary is overriding the content I dont know why so I allocated it within the function

```
    moreTableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [myDict setObject:countryTxt.text forKey:@"Country"];
    [myDict setObject:cityTxt.text forKey:@"City"];
    [myDict setObject:EscortsNumTxt1.text forKey:@"people"];
    [myDict setObject:fromDate.text forKey:@"Datetogo"];
    [myDict setObject:toDate.text forKey:@"Datetoreach"];

    [moreArr addObject:myDict];
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the array once like in your methos

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
    }


    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[moreArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSLog("%@",results); //Check that everything is in the right place

    // DO STUFF

    [results release];

}
```

Comment: This doesnt works for me as it is crashing, although I have overcome my problem myself, solution posted below